# Fork company repo as a regular GitHub user

Tags: github, fork

Can I fork a private company repo (from the organisation, I'm part of) as regular user, to have a private fork under my own (not company) account? A fork that is in no relation to company or it's (original) repo?

I tried the simpliest thing, that is forking my own fork. But that failed.

No mater, if I'm at `company/core` repository or `user/core` fork, whenver I'm clicking `Fork` button in GitHub, I see two options -- my user account and company account. None of these buttons works. When I hover my own button, I see `Click to visit the @user fork` tooltip. When I hover company logo, I see `You're already looking at this repository` (which is actually a little bit misleading, as I'm actually looking at my fork, not at original repository).

Is there any workaround for this? Can I have my own, regular user-based, private fork of company?

Comment: Organization private repositories and their forks can only be forked by members of that org.  You won't be able see, let alone fork, any private repos from an org that does not list your username in its list of members.  The only way you'll be able to fork this repo is if your company decides to make it a public repository.  

If you think about it, if there were a "workaround," there wouldn't actually be such a thing as private repos for an org, and they wouldn't actually be able to keep any of their code confidential if an employee could fork it to some random, non-org-member username.

Comment: Seems, you can. Only it is not called a "fork". See my answer or [this GitHub Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can. Only this is called [a mirror](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository), not a fork.

Steps are following:

1. Create new repository, that will act as your private "fork".
2. Get HTTPS / SSH addresses of both repositories and open console.
3. Execute `git clone --bare https://github.com/company/company-repository.git`.
4. `cd` to cloned local repository.
5. Execute `git push --mirror https://github.com/user/user-repository.git` (a "fork").
6. `cd` up one level and `rm -rf company-repository.git`.

These are instruction for one-time duplication ("forking") of a company repository as a regular user. Follow to [this GitHub Help page](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository) for more details and for instruction on performing periodic updates of such "fork".

Note, that step 3. is quite fast (up to speed of your connection; 1 MB/s at my side), while step 5 is often limited by GitHub to something around 60 kB/s. So, for large repositories, it usually takes a lot more time to finish.